# How can we scrape all 'Symbol' items into a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am trying to figure out how to scrape all 'symbol' elemnets from the URL below. I would like to put all symbol items into a list.

https://etfdb.com/screener/#page=1&tab=returns&sort_by=one_week_return&sort_direction=desc&asset_class=equity&one_week_return_start=2&one_month_return_start=5&ytd_start=20&fifty_two_week_start=30

I want to get this: `lst = ['NRGU', 'CHIE' .... 'PSCE', 'FXN']`

I tested this concept, but it gave me a lot more than I want...I don't know how to distill it down to just the 'symbol' items.

```
# Print All TR & TD ELements in Web Page
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd
import csv

url = "https://etfdb.com/screener/#page=1&tab=returns&sort_by=one_week_return&sort_direction=desc&asset_class=equity&one_week_return_start=2&one_month_return_start=5&ytd_start=20&fifty_two_week_start=30"
page = requests.get(url)
pagetext = page.text
print(pagetext)

soup = BeautifulSoup(pagetext, 'html.parser')

for row in soup.find_all('tr'):
    for col in row.find_all('td'):
        info1 = row.text
        print(info1)
        info2 = col.text
        print(info2)
```

Any thoughts on how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, data is loaded dynamically from external source via `API` as `POST` method as `json` format meaning they are using API to transmit data from browser to server that's why bs4 can't parse/mimic data and we can't pull such data from `HTML DOM`. So there are two options to grab data. 1. use an automation tool something like selenium 2. Extract data from API which is the easiest and the robust way.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
payload = {
    "asset_class": "equity",
    "fifty_two_week_start": "30",
    "one_month_return_start": "5",
    "one_week_return_start": "2",
    "only": [
        "meta",
        "data",
            "count"
    ],
    "page": 1,
    "sort_by": "one_week_return",
    "sort_direction": "desc",
    "tab": "returns",
    "ytd_start": "20"
    }

api_url= 'https://etfdb.com/api/screener/'
headers= {
    "content-type": "application/json",
    "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/104.0.0.0 Safari/537.36",
    }

lst=[]
for payload['page'] in range(1,3):
    req=requests.post(api_url,headers=headers,json=payload).json()

    
    for item in req['data']:
        lst.append({
            "symbol":item['symbol']['text']})

print(lst)
# df = pd.DataFrame(lst)
# print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
[{'symbol': 'NRGU'}, {'symbol': 'GUSH'}, {'symbol': 'ERX'}, {'symbol': 'DIG'}, {'symbol': 'EPV'}, {'symbol': 'CHIE'}, {'symbol': 'PXI'}, {'symbol': 'PXE'}, {'symbol': 'OIH'}, {'symbol': 'IEO'}, {'symbol': 'IEZ'}, {'symbol': 'FCG'}, 
{'symbol': 'FTXN'}, {'symbol': 'XOP'}, {'symbol': 'PSCE'}, {'symbol': 'XES'}, {'symbol': 'XLE'}, {'symbol': 'RYE'}, 
{'symbol': 'FENY'}, {'symbol': 'JHME'}, {'symbol': 'VDE'}, {'symbol': 'FILL'}, {'symbol': 'IYE'}, {'symbol': 'IXC'}, {'symbol': 'PXJ'}, {'symbol': 'FXN'}, {'symbol': 'NANR'}, {'symbol': 'MLPR'}, {'symbol': 'IGE'}, {'symbol': 'AMLP'}, {'symbol': 'AMZA'}]
```

Comment: That's brilliant! How did you figure that out? When you said, 'data is loaded dynamically from external source via API as POST method as json format', I basically understand that...but how did you get from my (very primitive) solution to your (very elegant) solution???

Comment: @ ASH, Thanks.  Not always but most of the time , my first task is to check out whether it contains API or not.  How did I figure out it? When data is loaded  dynamically?? Well If  you  make disabled JavaScript  from your browser and refresh/rerun the webpage then you will notice  that  most of the cases , content  didn't load properly or gone disappereard then understood that the website contains API. In this website, when I closed javascript then notice that all content didn't loaded completely. Then I  check out  API via Devtools > network tab > XHR.

Comment: Of couse, when you will check  out APl,  don't keep close JS.

Comment: I think I see it. Click on 'HXR' and you see 200 > Domain + File. So, you get that API, and then, create that headers= {...} thing. I think I understand this part. Finally, it looks like some kind of req=requests.post, which I think I understand. I guess that's it. I wouldn't have come up with this all by myself, but it's a great learning opportunity! Thanks again!!

Answer (score 1):

```py
import requests


def main(url):
    data = {
        "asset_class": "equity",
        "fifty_two_week_start": "30",
        "one_month_return_start": "5",
        "one_week_return_start": "2",
        "only": [
            "meta",
            "data",
            "count"
        ],
        "page": 1,
        "sort_by": "one_week_return",
        "sort_direction": "desc",
        "tab": "returns",
        "ytd_start": "20"
    }
    r = requests.post(url, json=data)
    symbols = [i['symbol']['text'] for i in r.json()['data']]
    print(symbols)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main('https://etfdb.com/api/screener/')
```